# Comparing DateTime objects

Tags: c#, timestamp

Goal - find out which DateTime is more recent.

Can I figure this out with this code:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(...); //let's say it was created on 1/1/2000

DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(...); //let's say it was create on 1/1/2011 

if (dt2.ToBinary() > dt1.ToBinary()) {
print dt2 is newer than dt1 }
```

Can I simply convert the DateTime objects to binary, then presume that the larger one is more recent?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (dt2 > dt1) {
print dt2 is newer than dt1 }
```

should be enough as DateTime overloads the comparison operators.

Answer (score 4):

You can usually do better than that:

```
if (dt2 > dt1)
```

The tricky bit is taking time zones into consideration... you can potentially use

```
if (dt2.ToUniversalTime() > dt1.ToUniversalTime())
```

but only if you know that any "local" times really are local in the system's time zone.

Dates and times in .NET are a bit of a mess :(

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.  `ToBinary()` returns an internal format that also stores time zone info.

Instead, you can compare the `DateTime`s directly:

```
if (dt2 > dt1)
```

`DateTime` overloads the comparison operators.

You could compare the `Ticks` property, but you shouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datetime.Compare

```
int iDiff = DateTime.Compare(new DateTime(2011, 02, 28), new DateTime(2011, 01, 30));
```

-1 = The Fisrt Date is Less than the Second
0 = The First Date is equal than the Second 
1 = The First Date is Greater than the Second

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` objects are comparable themselves, so

```
if (dt1>dt2)
  Console.WriteLine('dt1 is newer');
else if (dt1>dt2)
  Console.WriteLine('dt2 is newer');
else // they are equal
  Console.WriteLine('dt1 and dt2 are the same');
```

will work too.
In addition `DateTime` implements the `IComparable<DateTime>` interface, so you can do:

```
int result = dt1.CompareTo(dt2);
if (result > 0)
  Console.WriteLine('dt1 is newer');
else if (result < 0)
  Console.WriteLine('dt2 is newer');
else // result = 0
  Console.WriteLine('dt1 and dt2 are the same');
```

EDIT: This ignores time zones, local times, etc...